# Instances variables in subclass of NSButton and connecting new button with Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mouse, subclass, nsbutton

In order to access -mouseUp and -mouseDown events in a button I have subclassed NSButton and I also want to store a few extra variables within the object:

```
@interface MoveButton : NSButton{

    unsigned char cmd[3];
    unsigned char stop[3];
    int r;
    struct libusb_device_handle *devh;

}

-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent;
-(void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent;
-(void) setcommand:(char*)first:(char*)second:(char*)third (libusb_device_handle*)device_handle;
-(void) setLight: (char*) light;

@end
```

Within my window controller I have a number of instances of the subclass each connected to an element in Interface Builder through an IBOutlet.

```
@interface MainWindowController(){

    IBOutlet MoveButton * base_cw;
    IBOutlet MoveButton * base_ccw;

@end
```

Within the initWithWindow function each of the buttons are initialised:

```
 base_cw = [[MoveButton alloc] init];
 base_ccw = [[MoveButton alloc] init];
 [base_cw setcommand:"00" :"00" :"00":devh];
 [base_ccw setcommand:"00" :"00" :"00":devh];
```

In Interface builder I have changed the class property of each button to MoveButton and connected it to the correct IBOutlet.
However when a button is actually clicked on the UI errors are thrown up because the instance variables the it is trying to use are empty. Is it that I haven't connected the in-code object properly with the UI element or am I just going about it the wrong way entirely?

Comment: Have you initialised the class itself? and why you don't use ARC, no need of ivar, simply create property. and use _base_cw=allocinit etc

Answer (score 1):

Having the lines

```
base_cw = [[MoveButton alloc] init];
base_ccw = [[MoveButton alloc] init];
```

in your implementation of `-initWithWindow:` is a mistake.  These values will be overwritten by the time `-windowDidLoad` is called, assuming that you have hooked up the controls (your `MoveButton`s) to `MainWindowController` (File's Owner) in Interface Builder.  If you have *not* hooked up the controls (instances of `MoveButton`) in Interface Builder, you'll have even more problems.

After double-checking that you have hooked up `MainWindowController`'s ivars `base_cw` and `base_ccw` to the appropriate `MoveButton`s in Interface Builder, you just need to add the lines configuring the buttons to `-windowDidLoad`:

```
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    //...
    [base_cw setcommand:"00" :"00" :"00":devh];
    [base_ccw setcommand:"00" :"00" :"00":devh];
}
```

---

Your selector `setcommand::::` doesn't conform to Objective-C conventions.  A better name would be

```
- (void)setFirstCommand:(char *)firstCommand 
        secondCommand:(char *)secondCommand 
        thirdCommand:(char *)thirdCommand 
        deviceHandle:(libusb_device_handle *)deviceHandle;
```

Notice the use of a label for each argument (`secondCommand` for `secondCommand` and so forth) and the use of camel case (`setFirstCommand:...` rather than `setfirstcommand:... and so on).

Comment: The WindowController is instantiated within the NIB itself rather than being created programatically, so I can't get the windowDidLoad function to call, but I have moved all the initialisation of the MoveButton objects for the time being so that it definitely runs and from that point the MoveButton object contain the necessary data. I have connected all the IBOutlets to the elements on the window but I am still having the same problem of when the buttons are clicked all the ivars are empty.

Comment: Since your window controller is in your `xib`, use `-awakeFromNib` rather than `-windowDidLoad`.  If the outlets are properly set up in Interface Builder, your button instance variables will be non-`nil` at this point.

Comment: In general, though, it is not best practice to have your window controllers in your `xib`s.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! By using the declaration

```
IBOutlet MoveButton * base_cw;
```

It wasnt truly linking the in-code object to the UI object.

Replacing it with:

```
IBOutlet id base_cw
```

The link was properly established and messages to change the ivars were being sent to the correct object.

Many thank for the help given.